# Couldn't extract web table data using bs4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract a table data on this website `https://fuelkaki.sg/home`.

However, when I run the code below, it returned me an empty list `[]`. My final objective is to extract the word 'Caltex' on the first row of tbody and all the other data on the table but without getting past the empty list, I'm unable to do so. Furthermore, there is no error message so I'm baffled as to what I need to do too. Any advice is appreciated.

my_code.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://fuelkaki.sg/home"

r = requests.get(url = URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

rows = soup.select('tbody tr')

print(rows) # Returns empty list (no error)

row = rows[0]

name = rows.select_one('.fuel-name').text.strip()

print(name) # Returns attribute error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use selenium and BeautifulSop for the extract of dynamic content.Hope its help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
}
URL = "https://fuelkaki.sg/home"
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
page = webdriver.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(webdriver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.select('table', {'class': 'table'}):
    for tr in row.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        for i in tds:
            print(i.text)
```

Comment: I was hoping there is another way without having to use Selenium. Looks like I've got no choice. Thanks for your input.